# How to get count for different AWS resource types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3

is there any boto API to get count of all the resources inside an AWS service. For ex: For IAM, i want to get count of all Users, Roles, Groups etc.
I don't want to use list APIs like list_users etc, also i know AWS config has API get_discovered_resource_counts() but this works only when config is enabled.

Comment: I am not sure of an all encompassing API that can give you this count, but just curious about the use case here, is it for monitoring if you are nearing any of the resource limits?

Comment: The scopely-devops/skew project at github might be helpful. It's like an uber-boto3 and can enumerate resources across regions and across accounts.